# Silly Quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Suppose that I want to minimize the function $x^2$ subject to the contraint 
$$
ax\leq b,
$$
for some $b> 0$.  I solved the problem if the contraint is an equality but I'm not sure how to go about solving the slack case... I looked at KKT but I'm confused....

Comment: Linear Programming?

Comment: I might misunderstand the question (looking at the tags, which I am not familiar) but my interpretation is that $f(x) = x^2$ already has a global minimum. Restricting the input in this way has no impact on that minimum.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Assuming of course $a\geq0$ but even if not this problem seems to be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, suppose $b \ge 0$.

Then $x=0$ satisfies the contraint $ax\le b$, regardless of the value of $a$.

Hence, even with the constraint $ax\le b$, the minimum value of $x^2$ is $0$.

Next, suppose $b < 0$.

Consider cases . . .

If $a = 0$, the inequality $ax\le b$ reduces to $0\le b$, which is impossible (since $b < 0$), hence the feasible region is empty.

If $a > 0$, the inequality $ax\le b$ reduces to $x\le {\large{\frac{b}{a}}}$, hence, since ${\large{\frac{b}{a}}} < 0$, the minimum value of $x^2$ is $\bigl({\large{\frac{b}{a}}}\bigr)^2$.

If $a < 0$, the inequality $ax\le b$ reduces to $x\ge {\large{\frac{b}{a}}}$, hence, since ${\large{\frac{b}{a}}} > 0$, the minimum value of $x^2$ is $\bigl({\large{\frac{b}{a}}}\bigr)^2$.

Comment: What about the case where $b<0$...

Comment: @N00ber: I edited in a discussion for that case.

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks so much!